# How can I get back the value of iterations from this function to my main function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to return the `iterations` back to `main` from `JacobiMethod`, but it still shows `0` even when I write `return iterations;`

```
int JacobiMethod(double T[N][N], double c[N], double x[N], int iterations)
{
    double x_new[N];
    double x_prev[N];
    double tmp=0;
    while(magnitudeVectorDiff(x_new, x_prev) != 1)
    {   
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                tmp=tmp+T[i][j]*x[j];
            }
            x_new[i]=tmp+c[i];
            tmp=0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            x_prev[i]=x[i];
            x[i]=x_new[i];
        }
        iterations++;
    }
    return iterations;
}

int main()
{
    double A[N][N];
    double v[N];
    double x[N] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double LU[N][N];
    double Dinv[N][N];
    double T[N][N];
    double c[N];
    double x_new[N];
    double x_prev[N];
    int iterations=0;
    read_data_from_file(A, v);
    splitting_array(A, LU, Dinv);
    T_and_c(LU, Dinv, v, T, c);
    JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations);
    iterations=JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations);
    printArray(A);
    printVectorV(v);
    printf("Completed %d iterations (for tolerance = %lf).\n", iterations, TOL);
    printf("%d\n", iterations);
    printVector(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I've added the main function above but I didn't include all the other functions of the program, as they are not that important for this question.

Comment: `return iterations`? Or pass in a pointer to iterations.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't help. Shows that function returns void

Comment: Change the function return type?

Comment: Well... change the function type to `int` ...or use indirection with the last function argument as `int *iterations` and then `(*iterations)++;` and call the function with ... you have not shown that.

Comment: Tried both with double and int instead of void but didn't change anything

Comment: Show us the part of your code where you call this function and where you print the result

Comment: int main(void)
{
    double A[N][N];
    double v[N];
    double x[N]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double LU[N][N];
    double Dinv[N][N];
    double T[N][N];
    double c[N];
    double x_new[N];
    double x_prev[N];
    int iterations=0;
    read_data_from_file(A, v);
    splitting_array(A, LU, Dinv);
    T_and_c(LU, Dinv, v, T, c);
    JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations);
    printArray(A);
    printVectorV(v);
    printf("Completed %d iterations (for tolerance = %lf).\n", iterations, TOL);
    printf("%d\n", iterations);
    printVector(x);
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Hubson not in the comments, please edit your question to add this part of code.

Comment: Not trying to be rude but I really think you would benefit from pausing coding and going back to some systematic learning following a C book or tutorial. At the moment it seems you do not have a grasp of basic C concepts such as storing the return value from a function: `iterations = JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I moved the problem statement to the beginning of the post, so that readers can see it more easily. I also formatted your code slightly so that it's easier to read. The [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) has some advice you can use. Good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the return of your function in your variable for it to change:

```
iterations = JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations);
```

And in your function, as explined in the comment, you can `return iterations` and the return type of your function should be `int`.

Note that the `iterations` variables in the main and in your function `JacobiMethod` are 2 different variables. They are both local variables available only in their respective functions. They just have the same name, but they are not the same variable.

When the variable `iterations` changes in `JacobiMethod`, the variable in the `main` doesn't change.

That's why you need to return the value from your function and assign the return of your function in the main.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong but it still shows 0 to me.

Comment: I have added `return iterations` in the int JacobiMethod and `iterations=JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations)` right after calling the function

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else in your functions but since we don't know what's in it we can't help more. Try to debug your program. Add some `printf` in your `JacobiMethod`, in your `while` loop to see if it actually increments.

Comment: Already done it and it shows 764 iterations. I can add the edit I have done in my program if it helps.

Comment: sorry for troubling you this much but it's the first time I had problems with returning the count number from a function and hadn't done in a long time

Comment: Remove this line `JacobiMethod(T, c, x, iterations);` that's the problem, you are calling the method 2 times but only the second time your store the return value.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice day and I promise I will learn more of the basics soon haha